# (in R) how to know the yearly variation/ check the mean value per year, for different years?

Tags: r, time-series

I have data of N and C for different years. Need to check the annual variation for each one (N and C). I thought about plotting the mean value (+-SE) for each given year, but don't know how to look for it.

For ex, my data looks like this picture
(but with much more data, and for more years):
[image]

and I would like my plot to look like [image]

Comment: What have you tried so far, Natalia? This question is probably better suited for StackOverflow, as this is more-so a programming question than geared toward statistics.

Answer (score 1):

This question is probably best directed to StackOverflow.

You can use a number of different methods to get your desired result. The `tidyverse` can be helpful for its use of functional programming.

```
library(tidyverse)
# calculate the standard deviation for the two fields
sd_N <- sd(data$N)
sd_C <- sd(data$C)

# This will get us the plot for field `N`
data %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(mean_N = mean(N)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = mean_N)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_N - sd_N, ymax = mean_N + sd_N))
```